# Express: subfolder paths having issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, filesystems

I have a project, which is meant to be both downloaded as a standalone folder (No Node/Express), that can be run directly from the file system, and to be worked on in a local environment (localhost using node/express). Right now my file system looks like this:

```
main folder
  client
    images
      Image1.png
      Image2.jpeg
    sounds
      Sound1.mp3
      Sound2.wav
    js
      loader.js
      Engine.js
      ...
    main.mjs
    index.html
  
  app.js
  node_modules
    ...
  package.json
  package-lock.json
```

I need the client folder to be run on its own, loaded from the file system, so going to `localhost` or opening the `index.html` file does the same thing. However, right now I need to change every link inside of the client folder for this to work.

For example, inside of `loader.js`, I have a line that looks something like this:

```js
Image1 = new Image();
Image1.src = '/client/images/image1.png'
```

But when It is run as a stand alone file, it needs to be:

```
Image1 = new Image();
Image1.src = '../images/image1.png'
```

How do I set up my express server to handle the second condition and treat it as the first? Right now it will not send the files over, will just respond with a `404` for any file that is requested, except for the index. It looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/',(req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
})

app.use('./', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
app.use('../', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

const port = process.env.PORT || 2000;

server.listen(port);
```

I am new to express, so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "run it as a stand-alone file"?  Do you mean "load it directly from the file system with no server"?  If so, you should not be trying to design for both cases.  Your server provides functionality that the plain file system does not as URLs are not necessarily 100% replications of the file system.  Why does it matter at all that you can load this file without a server?

Comment: I have to upload a folder to another site, which runs it on its own server. However, I am using js modules, which won't work without a server, so to test it locally, before I upload it (which takes some time) I need it to run on a local server

Comment: So, I repeat what do you mean "run it as a stand-alone file"?

Comment: Crtl-o, chose the index file, and everything works

Comment: Run a local server to test locally and load your web page through that local server, not directly from the file system.  It's a completely different thing to design a web page to work stand-alone using only the file system than it is for your server.  It's just wasted development time to try to make it work that way.  Just run a local copy of your server and then you're testing the actual way it will work after uploaded.

Comment: Ok, I didn't think it was possible, just had to check.

Comment: Just use `localhost` as the domain in the URL and the browser will look for a server on your own local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it was an easy fix, just use:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Creating virtual paths was the issue, so by omitting the first argument, everything works now.

`./` refers to the current directory, `../` is one up, and `/js` is the js folder.